# jq: Unable to retrieve a key/value from Json file using jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, jq

I have the below JSON from the curl output and I need to retrieve the IP address from it. I tried the below jq query, but I am getting the below error. I tried several other ways of doing it, but no luck

`curl -sH "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -i http://${AMBARI_IP}:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip | jq '.[] | {.items.Hosts.ip}'`

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | {.items.Hosts.ip}
jq: 1 compile error
(23) Failed writing body
```

below is the output of curl

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 21:04:27 GMT
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: AMBARISESSIONID=123344.node0;Path=/;HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
User: admin
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "host_name" : "test123.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.135.3.119"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test001.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test001.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.33"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test002.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test002.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.34"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test003.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test003.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.35"
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: What's the intended purpose of the `.[] |` here? That would make sense if you were getting back a list; not so much when the top-level item is an object.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:`.[]` can be used for any composite entity. Et voilà !

Comment: ,@peak, it can, surely, but I'm not sure it's _sensible_ in this case; in the iterating-over-objects case you're discarding data (I forget if it iterates over keys or values, and am not much inclined to look it up -- it's basically never the right thing IMHO to not handle key and value together as a pair).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `jq '.items[].Hosts.ip'`. This grabs the `.items` key from the outer object, iterates the items array, then pulls the value from the path `.Hosts.ip` from each object.

```
PS > cat a.json
{
  "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip",
  "items" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "host_name" : "test123.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.135.3.119"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test001.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test001.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.33"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test002.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test002.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.34"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://10.0.0.33:8080/api/v1/hosts/test003.sil.dev.test.com",
      "Hosts" : {
        "cluster_name" : "test_cluster",
        "host_name" : "test003.sil.dev.test.com",
        "ip" : "10.0.0.35"
      }
    }
  ]
}
PS > cat a.json | jq '.items[].Hosts.ip'
"10.135.3.119"
"10.0.0.33"
"10.0.0.34"
"10.0.0.35"
PS > cat a.json | jq -r '.items[].Hosts.ip'
10.135.3.119
10.0.0.33
10.0.0.34
10.0.0.35
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I am getting the below error 
`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9`
when I execute the  below. I am facing same issue for all jq that i try. 
`curl -sH "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -i http://${AMBARI_IP}:8080/api/v1/hosts?fields=Hosts/host_name,Hosts/ip | jq '.items | .[] | .Hosts.ip'`

Comment: Your curl call fails for me because I don't have `${AMBARI_IP}`, so please edit your post to show the exact JSON you're working with after the curl call completes. There's no need to do it all in one step. You can simplify the problem by separating the commands. Posting your text verbatim is important, otherwise answerers have to make assumptions that might not apply to your case and confusion ensues.

Comment: @Eva The `-i` option to `curl` tells it to include the HTTP headers in the output (the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, `Date: ..` stuff). That's not valid JSON, so `jq` gets errors trying to parse it. You need to either remove the `-i` option, or split off just the JSON part of the output before passing it to `jq`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks, I missed the significance of that flag. Here's you in 2014 explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24566979/6243352

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, -i was casing problems in my case.